# How to set cron job in yii

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I am quite newbie to yii. I am working on a project.

I have written a function to send automatic reminder to clients

say this function is at url :

`http://somedomain.com/index.php/somecontroller/someaction`

I want to set the cron for this url.

one method is that I should write `GET cron_job_url`.

But I dont want to use the url for my cron.I only want to use physical path of the controller and action. Is this possible with `yii` ?

Comment: No I don't believe it is unless you don't use any models or anything else from Yii because those files haven't been included if you just include the controller's php file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use a cron job, I'd suggest to write a `yiic` command instead of calling a URL. It's very simple and you don't have to deal with URL access permissions.

Create a new class that extends from `CConsoleCommand` and implement either a `run()` method or some actions as you would in a controller. You can find more information on console commands [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console). You have to save the command to the `protected/commands` directory and the class name must end in `Command`.

If your command is called `DemoCommand` then you can call it from a cron job as `/path/to/your/webroot/protected/yiic demo`.

Comment: Hey I am using that  but I am not getting that how can I call models and controller in this command folder

Comment: You can do whatever you want in such a command and use any class or model you like - much the same as in a controller action. Just make sure, that you didn't miss to add any custom `import` paths you may have in your `main.php`. You'd have to add them to your `console.php`, too.