# PHP iconv error using Zend Lucene when executing script via cron, but not on commandline

Tags: linux, zend-framework, yii, lucene, cron

I am executing a PHP script via the command line which, for a specific user, runs fine when executed on the commandline, but when the exact same command is put into the same user's crontab, a PHP iconv error is returned.

The commandline is utilising the Yii framework and the Zend Lucene library, but I'm not sure if that's pertinent.

I've made all executable and script paths absolute in the crontab line and can verify that it works when executed directly on the commandline.

I wrapped the actual PHP invocation in a one-line shell script, as I read elsewhere here that this solved a similar problem for someone, but no joy.

**The command successfully executed on the commandline is:**

```
/bin/sh /var/www/yii-projects/projectname/protected/scripts/buildIndex.sh >> /var/lucene/lucene.log
```

**The content of the buildIndex.sh script is:**

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/yii-projects/projectname/protected/scripts/cron.php lucene buildIndex
```

**And the crontab line is:**

```
*/10 * * * * /bin/sh /var/www/yii-projects/projectname/protected/scripts/buildIndex.sh >> /var/lucene/lucene.log
```

**The error shown in the log when the crontab executes is:**

```
PHP Error[8]: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string
    in file /var/www/yii-projects/projectname/protected/vendors/Zend/Search/Lucene/Analysis/Analyzer/Common/Text.php at line 58

0 /var/www/yii-projects/projectname/protected/vendors/Zend/Search/Lucene/Analysis/Analyzer/Common/Text.php(58): iconv()

1 /var/www/yii-projects/projectname/protected/vendors/Zend/Search/Lucene/Analysis/Analyzer.php(125): Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Text_CaseInsensitive->reset()

2 /var/www/yii-projects/projectname/protected/vendors/Zend/Search/Lucene/Index/SegmentWriter/DocumentWriter.php(98): Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Text_CaseInsensitive->setInput()

3 /var/www/yii-projects/projectname/protected/vendors/Zend/Search/Lucene/Index/Writer.php(244): Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_SegmentWriter_DocumentWriter->addDocument()

4 /var/www/yii-projects/projectname/protected/vendors/Zend/Search/Lucene.php(1410): Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Writer->addDocument()

5 /var/www/yii-projects/projectname/protected/vendors/Zend/Search/Lucene/Proxy.php(500): Zend_Search_Lucene->addDocument()

6 /var/www/yii-projects/projectname/protected/commands/LuceneCommand.php(97): Zend_Search_Lucene_Proxy->addDocument()

7 unknown(0): LuceneCommand->actionBuildIndex()

8 /var/www/yii-projects/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/console/CConsoleCommand.php(173): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs()

9 /var/www/yii-projects/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/console/CConsoleCommandRunner.php(68): LuceneCommand->run()

10 /var/www/yii-projects/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/console/CConsoleApplication.php(92): CConsoleCommandRunner->run()

11 /var/www/yii-projects/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/base/CApplication.php(162): CConsoleApplication->processRequest()

12 /var/www/yii-projects/projectname/protected/scripts/cron.php(14): CConsoleApplication->run()
```

**I cannot think of any reason why there is any difference, given the measures taken, and the fact that the user is the same in both cases.**

Please help!

Thanks

Edit - I should also confirm that the underlying data that is being indexed is not changing - I've executed both scenarios alternately many times and get the above results consistently.

Comment: You should rather create a yiic command. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235235/how-to-set-cron-job-in-yii

Comment: Hi Michael - cron.php does invoke a Yii CCommand (LuceneCommand with action buildIndex()). The Yii command is invoked in both cases (where it workds and where it fails).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necessary shell environment variables are not available to crontab job, so added this to irishhp users's crontab:

```
PATH=/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

which resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the **-f** switch and directly from crontab:

```
/usr/bin/php -f /var/www/yii-projects/projectname/protected/scripts/cron.php lucene buildIndex
```

Also are you sure that the text of the command you are passing is in UTF8? Could there be some other symbol there? Maybe a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)? You can check this with a HEX editor - open your shell script, omit all the letters and see what's left. Usually a BOM in UTF8 is **EF BB BF** but it may not be a bom at all. Just check.